# Recarregar ancoras

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site - plm87.com.br/Davi - esse é o link temporario.

Então, a duvida é o seguinte: quando eu clico nos links do menu as ancoras funcionam normalmente. porém, quando eu clico nos botões de "ver mais" na parte de especialidades as ancoras desconfiguram.

Então, preciso de algum método, que seja em js, html, css ou qualquer outra linguagem para recarregar a precisão das ancoras.

Me ajudem PF eu pesquisei bastante e não achei ninguem com esse mesmo problema.

Obrigado. :)

Comment: mesmo sem abrir o botão "Ver mais" a ancora não é precisa. Mas quando abre fica muito desconfigurado

Comment: não entendo nada desse assunto, mas o site está muito legal >)

Comment: Não faço ideia do que queres dizer com _"ancoras precisas"_ ... podes dar um exemplo ou montar um jsFiddle para percebermos melhor?

Comment: Ao clicar nos links das Ancoras ele não vai para o lugar certo. ele rola para um lugar meio que "nada a ver"